# How to change file permission in windows while the process is running using python?

Tags: python, windows

I need to change the file permission while the process is running.

I cannot use cacls or something similar because it changes the file permission of the file before actually running it.

I have tried using [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/downloads.php) and have changed the file permission while the process is running and it worked wonderfully but I need something similar that I could apply through a python code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you referring to privledges (admin/user/guest/etc)? or permisions(read-only/etc)? (just to clarify I doubt I can actually help you with either)

Comment: Im pretty sure there is no way to elevate privledges from a running process  ... however you could probably create a spawn process that is  elevate that performs the required operations and then exits... you can probably make it "appear" to be the same process to the user